# What is the syntax of the Ruby on Rails Time.at function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have seen the Time.at function used [here](https://richonrails.com/articles/facebook-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails).  What is the format of the  `Time.at` function?

Comment: I do not see a slightest hint on the benefit/use of this question/answer having the [perfect documentation on the topic](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Time.html#method-c-at).

Comment: When I searched for this on google, with several attempts, it did not yield the perfect documentation on the subject. It was only after I started to research this question that I found the right documentation.  The perfect documentation on the subject is of no use if it cannot be found. Different people search in different ways, so although this question may not of be use to you, it will be of use to others.  I  also note someone else (totally unrelated to me) has upvoted my answer, so proving there is the slightest hint of benefit to this question.

Comment: Just so you understand, when I originally searched with ```ruby on rails Time.at api``` this  page, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-at,  was the main one returned which was gave me no information at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it as `Time.at(n)`, where `n` is the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (1970-1-1 00:00:00 UTC). `n` can take decimal values, see [ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Time.html).